# How long is the life of a memory stick?

Tags: memory, ssd, ramdisk

I want to use some memory which is integrated in the motherboard, to make a ramdisk, so that the SSD won't be written to as an internet video buffer.

But I doubt that life of the memory would be too long if I do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking...you just want to use your RAM as a RAM disk? That won't affect the life of your memory components if you do that. The only thing you'll risk is your data, since turning off power to the machine erases the contents of memory.

Comment: From the way the question is titled, I assumed he had some sort of SD card or whatever on the motherboard that he wanted to use.

Comment: Low quality (unclear) + off-topic == vote to close in place.

Comment: Yup, don't know why this was migrated here.

Comment: @Ward well nicely done Ward, make it more confusing.. I read your comment and thought he must be talking about a Flash memory stick e.g. USB or SD card.. I almost downvoted this answer because of your slightly misleading comment along with his misleading title.  But indeed, as he says "I want to use some memory which is integrated in the motherboard,"  The answer is as Bart says, it won't shorten the life really. No more than using memory normally would.